# What are the pros and cons of different metrics for evaluating a logistic regression model?

Tags: logistic, goodness-of-fit, deviance, concordance, hosmer-lemeshow-test

In the ***data science*** world, I have always evaluated the performance of logistic regression models simply using ROC/AUC. However recently, I've read from some ***traditional statistics*** source about some measures of a logistic regression, including:

for goodness-of-fit: **Pearson statistic**, **Deviance**, and **Hosmer-Lemeshow statistic**;
for quality of prediction: **Nagelkerke's $R^2$**, **Concordance** measure.

So, which metrics are better for what scenario? Also, I'm pretty confused how goodness-of-fit is different from predictability?

Comment: Related non-duplicate: [Which pseudo-$R^2$ measure is the one to report for logistic regression (Cox & Snell or Nagelkerke)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/3559/1352)

Comment: Note that Hosmer-Lemeshow test is now considered obsolete:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/273999/11887