# What is the accurate null hypothesis for the Hosmer-Lemeshow test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, hosmer-lemeshow-test

I've read some works on the Hosmer-Lemeshow test (HLT) but still I'm uncertain what is the exact null hypothesis for the HLT. I'd like to formulate a nullhypothesis as precisely as possible.

I think *the fitted model is significant* says everything and nothing.

*The observed frequencies equal the estimated frequencies* is more acccurate for a pearson chi-square test and misses the logistic model.

I prefer this one:

$$\hat{\pi}_{k_j} = \pi_{{k_j}_0} \; (j =1, \ldots, c_k) (k=1, \ldots, g)$$

where

$\hat{\pi}_{k_j}$ is the from the logistic model estimated probability

$\pi_{{k_j}_0}$ is the real but unknown probalbility

$c_k$ is the number of covariate patterns in the $k$th grouop

$g$ is the number of groups

What are your suggestions?

### Edit

As I think now, the proper null hypothesis is in fact *The model fits* and the alternative is *the model does not fit*.
(Hosmer, Lemeshow: Applied logistic Regression, Kuß: [Globale Anpassungstests im logistischen Regressionsmodell](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Oliver_Kuss/publication/33432282_Globale_Anpassungstests_im_logistischen_Regressionsmodell_bei_fehlenden_Messwiederholungen/links/0a85e53bff5f7b81f9000000/Globale-Anpassungstests-im-logistischen-Regressionsmodell-bei-fehlenden-Messwiederholungen.pdf))

That means the HL-test evaluates the fitted model.

Comment: Hosmer-Lemeshow is considered obsolete:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/273966/logistic-regression-with-poor-goodness-of-fit-hosmer-lemeshow

Comment: thank you for your comment, even this question is old!